# Doctrine 2 - not able to save one to many self-reference relationship

Tags: doctrine, one-to-many, categories, self, persist

I have a problem saving a one to many self-reference relationship, both parent and children are saved properly on the database, but Im getting parent_id null for the children.
I folloed the doctrine example ... but no idea

```
namespace CD\Entity;
/**
 * @Entity
 */

class Category {


/**
* @Id 
* @Column(type="integer")
* @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
*/
private $id;

/** @Column(type="string",length=50) */
private $name;


/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent;


// setters and getters ...
```

}

and my controller here:

```
public function insertAction()
{

    $cm = new CD\Entity\Category();
    $cc = new CD\Entity\Category();

    $cm->name = 'mainCat';
    $cc->name = 'childCat';

    $cm->children = array($cc);

    $this->_em->persist($cm);
    $this->_em->flush();        

}
```

I really dont know what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions), particularly the [tree](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) extension? It makes work like this extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist ALL of your entities. 
And after running (assuming you use doctrine)

> doctrine:generate:entities CD/Entity

Your will have a function named "Category->addChildren" which should be used to add children to an existing category entity.

Try this:

```
public function insertAction()
{

    $cm = new CD\Entity\Category();
    $cc = new CD\Entity\Category();

    $cm->setName('mainCat');
    $cc->setName('childCat');

    $cm->addChildren($cc);

    $this->_em->persist($cm);        
    $this->_em->persist($cc);        

    $this->_em->flush();        

}
```